# Simple Constructor Initialization List

Tags: c++

I want to initialize one of the class variables to max of unsigned long long with something like this:

```
ClassA():
 maxvalue(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max())
{

}
```

Is it ok to do this? Can I use

```
std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()
```

in the intialization list?

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from trying this?

Comment: @KerrekSB: the fact that many operations are subtly and silently undefined in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This will work as long as `maxvalue` is able to be constructed from `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`.